# How to change the color inside double tags in vscode theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the community material theme ocean, but I want to change the color of texts inside double tags. Any way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: show a code example, I don't know of a language that has `double tags`

Answer (score 0):

Open finder

Press cmd+shift+h to open users folder

Go to users/your user name

Press cmd+shift+. To open hidden files

Go to .vscode/extensions/sdras.night-owl /themes/Night owl-color-theme.json(In my case its night owl theme.)

Drag and Open the file in vscode

Open the html file you want to customise

Select the div element and press cmd+shift+p

Select developer: inspector editor token and scopes

Select the textmatescope eg: entity.name.tag.js

Comment: changing the extension files is a bad idea, you can customize all colors in your `settings.json` file